# Jersey injects wrong SecurityContext

Tags: java, jersey, guice, hk2

We recently integrated Guice with Jersey via the 'guice-bridge', and had to upgrade the dependency versions in the process. But then in production sub-resources (only them) sometimes had the wrong SecurityContext injected, with the principal from another thread! This behaviour seems completely random and never appeared before. **How can we fix this?**

This is the authentication filter:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // abort if user is not authenticated
        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new MySecurityContext(...));
      }
}
```

This is the root-resource:

```
@Path("/root-resource")
public class RootResource extends BaseResource {

    @Path("{rootResourceId}/sub-resource")
    public SubResource subResource(@PathParam("rootResourceId") String id) {
        return SubResource.create(this, id);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the sub-resource:

```
@Provider
public class SubResource extends BaseResource {

    public static SubResource create(RootResource root, String rootResourceId) {
        SubResource r = root.createSubResource(SubResource.class);
        ... // further setup
        return r;
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{subResourceId}")
    public void update(@PathParam("subResourceId") String subResourceId) {
        checkUserHasAccessToResource(subResourceId, context); // BOOM ?#!
        ...
    }   
}
```

And this is the base class:

```
public abstract class BaseResource {

    private ResourceContext resourceContext;
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    protected final <T extends AuthResource> T createSubResource(Class<T> resourceClass) {
        return resourceContext.getResource(resourceClass);
    }

    ...

    @Context
    public void setResourceContext(ResourceContext resourceContext) {
        this.resourceContext = resourceContext;
    }

    @Context
    public void setSecurityContext(SecurityContext securityContext) {
        this.securityContext = securityContext;
    }
}
```

PS: We use JDK7, Jersey 2.10.2 and HK2 2.3.0-b04.

**EDIT**

The SecurityContext implementation:

```
public class MySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    private final MyUserPrincipal userPrincipal;
    private final boolean isSecure;
    private final String authScheme;

    public MySecurityContext(MyUserPrincipal userPrincipal, boolean isSecure, String authScheme) {
        this.userPrincipal = userPrincipal;
        this.isSecure = isSecure;
        this.authScheme = authScheme;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return userPrincipal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return userPrincipal.isInRole(role);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return isSecure;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return authScheme;
    }
}
```

And the principal:

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements Principal {

    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String[] roles;

    public MyUserPrincipal(String userId, String userName, String[] roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return userName + " (" + userId + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecureLogin() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void reloadUser() {
    }

    public boolean isInRole(String role) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually getting a `SecurityContext` from a different thread or a `SecurityContext` with the `Principal` from another thread? If it's the latter, can you post the code where you retrieve your `Principal`? If it's the former, I'd put some logging around your `SecurityContext` setter to see if the correct `SecurityContext` is getting injected.

Comment: @Baldy I added the implementation of the SecurityContext & Principal. Nothing unusual, I think. That's why I believe the wrong SecurityContext is injected.

Comment: If you log the instance id of `MySecurityContext` in your filter and then again in your `BaseResource` setter you should be able to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few other versions of HK2 this behaviour just stopped. Scary.